# How can i prevent users from entering characters, strings and empty space using JOptionpane

Tags: java, string, char, int, joptionpane

How can I prevent users from entering characters, strings and empty spaces using `JOptionPane`? I've ravaged the internet for answers, but nothing came up. Please help, I need this done in three days. 
Here's my code:

```
int num, ctr, ctrodd=0, ctreven=0;
for (ctr=1;ctr<=15;ctr++)
{
    num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number "));

    if  (!num.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That's not a number!");
        ctr--;
        num.next();
    }
    else if (num%2==0)
    {
        ctreven++;
    }
    else if (num%2==1)
    {
        ctrodd++;
    }
    ctr++;
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Odd"+ctrodd+"\neven"+ctreven);
```

Answer (score 1):

Insetad of this:

```
 if  (!num.hasNextInt()) 
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That's not a number!");
    ctr--;
    num.next();
    }
```

try with this:

```
while (!num.hasNextInt()) 
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That's not a number!");
num.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call JOptionPane.showOptionDialog with a JFormattedTextField and a MaskFormatter.  The MaskFormatter can limit what kinds of characters are allowed to be entered at individual positions.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html

Describes all of the characters.

This code allows the user to enter up to but not more than 4 digits.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter(
            "####"));
    field.setColumns(10);
    field.setEnabled(true);
    field.setEditable(true);
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Message", null, 0, 0, null,
            new Object[]
            { field }, field);
    System.out.println(field.getText());
}
```

Comment: great but how can i use this in an if else statement